# Using Numpy vectorization instead of parallelly looping over two list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists or arrays of uneven length (let's say `arr_a`, `arr_b`).  I want to form a third array/list of tuples where the first element of the tuple take the value of `arr_a[1st element] - arr_b[1st element]` and the second element of the tuple taking `arr_a[1st element] - arr_b[2nd element]` and then the next tuple taking `(arr_a[2nd_element]-arr_b[2nd_element], arr_a[2nd_element] - arr_b[3rd_element])` and so on. The code below achieves this using a for loop. But I want to find out if this can be achieved through some sort NumPy vectorizing, broadcasting approach.
please note `arr_a` and `arr_b` are of not equal length ( `len(arr_b) = len(arr_a)+1`)

```
arr_a = np.random.randint(low = 0,high = 10,size = 10)
arr_b = np.random.randint(low = 0,high = 10,size = 11)

out:
arr_a : [4 8 6 3 3 7 8 6 0 2]
arr_b : [8 8 9 6 1 6 1 5 8 3 1]

list_c = []
for i,j in zip(range(len(arr_a)),range(len(arr_b))):
    list_c.append((arr_a[i]-arr_b[i],arr_a[i]-arr_b[i+1]))

out:
list_c : [(-4, -4), (0, -1), (-3, 0), (-3, 2), (2, -3), (1, 6), (7, 3), (1, -2), (-8, -3), (-1, 1)]
```

Comment: Numpy isnt going to help if you want tuples

Comment: I don't mind nested lists or arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try `zip` with `numpy`:

```
>>> list(zip(arr_a - arr_b[:-1], arr_a - arr_b[1:]))
[(-4, -4),
 (0, -1),
 (-3, 0),
 (-3, 2),
 (2, -3),
 (1, 6),
 (7, 3),
 (1, -2),
 (-8, -3),
 (-1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the data in two columns rather than a tuple (which does not play well with numpy given that the data would be an object rather than a numeric dtype):

```
>>> (arr_a - np.array([arr_b[:-1], arr_b[1:]])).T
array([[-4, -4],
       [ 0, -1],
       [-3,  0],
       [-3,  2],
       [ 2, -3],
       [ 1,  6],
       [ 7,  3],
       [ 1, -2],
       [-8, -3],
       [-1,  1]])
```